# getting an error "Unsupported Processor" when installing windows 10

Tags: windows-10, windows-11, windows-installation, amd-ryzen

I've recently bought a new PC. I have a Ryzen 5 3600 and was planning to get a B550 motherboard but the store only has B450M-Pro II available so I didn't really have a choice.

After I assembled the PC, I've plugged in my bootable USB drive to start installing Windows 10; I got the error "Unsupported Processor" BSoD error right after Windows pops up for the initial installation. I thought that it might just need a BIOS update.

- I've updated the BIOS to the latest version but still got the same error and thought, that's strange, the website indicates that the motherboard does support the CPU and I have already updated the BIOS to the latest version.
- I've tried reinstalling the bootable drive using media creation tool and creating bootable USB using rufus but still got the same error.
- I've already tried resetting the BIOS to it's default settings, reseated the CMOS battery,
- swapped the RAM slots,
- tried installing Windows 11 but I still keep getting the same error.
- tried installing using just 1 ram stick still the same error.

I've ran out of ideas already and I don't know what to do anymore.

*UPDATE:
I was able to successfully install Linux Mint without any issues. Do I need to change something from the BIOS settings for me to install Windows OS?

*I've also tried changing some BIOS settings like changing the TPM versions and still got the same error.

- also tried using a different USB drive for the installer but still the same issue

Below are the specs of my PC:

- CPU: Ryzen 5 3600
- GPU: gtx 1650 super
- Mobo: B450M-PRO II
- RAM: 2x 8GB 2666 MHz
- Storage: M.2 240GB transcend
- PSU: 600 W

Comment: Where/when exactly do you see this error message and how does it look? If possible, please provide a screenshot or photo.

Comment: you say you "installed windows 11". But how? you say your computer doesn't boot.

Comment: sorry forgot to mention it's a BSoD error.. it @daniel pops up right after Windows starts loading up for the initial setup.. I don't really have a screenshot since I'm now preparing to go to sleep.. pardon my choice of words, what I meant to say was tried to install Windows 11

Comment: Unsupported Processor shouldn't block the installation.

Comment: You may have inadvertently disabled critical CPU features in BIOS. Check that all CPU features are enabled.

Comment: @DeviruchiDDevourer - So are you trying to install Windows 11 or Windows 10? If Windows 10 is already installed why are you trying to install Windows 10? [Edit] your question instead of submitting confusing commentary

Comment: @harrymc do you perhaps have any information on what those features are that needs to be enabled?

Comment: @Ramhound thank you for the feedback. I have updated the post

Comment: Can a Linux Live USB boot successfully?

Comment: @harrymc I haven't tried this one yet.. I'll see if I can do it, thanks

Comment: @DeviruchiDDevourer - Just want to ask what might be an obvious answer, you are attempting to install, Windows 10 21H2, correct?

Comment: @Ramhound thank you for the reply. Im not quite sure about the version but I am indeed trying to install Windows 10. It's probably the latest version since I downloaded the ISO using media creation tool.

Comment: Mount the ISO within a copy of Windows and then use the appropriate DISM to list which images are contained on the ISO.

Comment: had it returned to the store and they said that they will need to reflash the bios.. I have to pay for the reflash since updating the bios voids the warranty

Comment: "since updating the bios voids the warranty" - You could have updated it yourself.  The firmware is on the OEM's [website](https://www.asus.com/Motherboards-Components/Motherboards/TUF-Gaming/TUF-GAMING-B450M-PRO-II/HelpDesk_BIOS/).  I have never heard that updating your BIOS voids the warranty.  **It appears you might be paying for a service that should be free**  [Full Instructions](https://www.asus.com/support/FAQ/1012815/)

Comment: I've returned to the store and they tested it again after flashing the BIOS and it still got the same error.. they ruled out that it's the processor that's faulty.. they didn't have a replacement so the only option I got is downgrading to Ryzen 5 4650g.. this is the last time I'll be buying from a physical store near me..

Answer (score 0):

the store ruled out that the processor was faulty and got downgraded to Ryzen 5 4650g.. It sucks to be in my city.. should have just ordered online